# 403 Forbidden Error on Apache2 server

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

Just backed up a site to my local computer using **CPanel**.

I unzipped the file then placed it in `/var/www`.

Now my problem is that when I try to access HTML/PHP files from the `public_html` folder for the site via a browser (`localhost/ndovucard/public_html/modules/contact_us.php`), I get the 403 Forbidden Error by Apache2 server, and yes I did `sudo chmod 755 /var/www`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www
```

and show your /var/log/

Answer (score 2):

There are can be several reasons why you are getting **403 Forbidden Error **

First check out weather you are denying permission to an `.htaccess file`  and 
that your apache2 is configured to allow htaccess file overide.
Check out your apache2  sites-available by using this command

in order to make your .htaccess files ( if you have any) work as expected, you need to edit this file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

and then Look for a section that looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None // change **`None`** to  **`All`**
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
            # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
            #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>
```

. You need to reload Apache in order this change to  have an effect:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

OR

```
   sudo service apache2 restart
```

If that is not the case, you have have permission set not correctly as you have said .

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/yourProjectFolderHer* -R
```

Hope that may help